# Using multiple S3 buckets with carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have just recently setup my rails 3.2 app to use the carrierwave gem and upload files to S3. What I don't see is the ability to use a different bucket per uploader. Does anyone know if this is a possiblity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple buckets is not currently supported by CarrierWave. You can separate files between uploaders by adding prefixes (folders) to the `store_dir`. Pull requests are welcome though if this is something you'd like to work on!

Comment: I see this document in the wiki (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Store-private-public-uploads-in-different-Cloud-Files-Containers-with-Fog). Can you specify different containers using Rackspace but just not Amazon?

Answer (score 18):

The bucket is specified via the fog_directory config. This configuration option is defined on the uploader and could simply be overwritten with your own method.

Just add the following to your uploader:

```
def fog_directory
  # your bucket name here
end
```

Answer (score 16):

The [carrierwave wiki explains how to use a separate s3 bucket for each uploader](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Define-different-storage-configuration-for-each-Uploader.):

```
def initialize(*)
  super

  self.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',              # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'YOURAWSKEYID',     # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'YOURAWSSECRET',    # required
  }
  self.fog_directory = "YOURBUCKET"
end
```

Comment: I think this is the most correct answer for this question.